# Node.js JSON.parse on object creation vs. with getter property

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, coffeescript

This is largely an *'am I doing it right / how can I do this better'* kind of topic, with some concrete questions at the end. If you have other advice / remarks on the text below, even if I didn't specifically ask those questions, feel free to comment.

---

I have a MySQL table for users of my app that, along with a set of fixed columns, also has a text column containing a JSON config object. This is to store variable configuration data that cannot be stored in separate columns because it has different properties per user. There doesn't need to be any lookup / ordering / anything on the configuration data, so we decided this would be the best way to go.

When querying the database from my Node.JS app (running on Node 0.12.4), I assign the JSON text to an object and then use Object.defineProperty to create a getter property that parses the JSON string data when it is needed and adds it to the object.

The code looks like this:

```
user = 
    uid: results[0].uid
    _c: results[0].user_config # JSON config data as string

Object.defineProperty user, 'config',
    get: ->
        @c = JSON.parse @_c if not @c?
        return @c
```

**Edit:** above code is Coffeescript, here's the (approximate) Javascript equivalent for those of you who don't use Coffeescript:

```
var user = {
    uid: results[0].uid,
    _c: results[0].user_config // JSON config data as string
};

Object.defineProperty(user, 'config', {
    get: function() {
        if(this.c === undefined){
            this.c = JSON.parse(this._c);
        }
        return this.c;
    }
});
```

I implemented it this way because parsing JSON blocks the Node event loop, and the config property is only needed about half the time (this is in a middleware function for an express server) so this way the JSON would only be parsed when it is actually needed. The config data itself can range from 5 to around 50 different properties organised in a couple of nested objects, not a huge amount of data but still more than just a few lines of JSON.

Additionally, there are three of these JSON objects (I only showed one since they're all basically the same, just with different data in them). Each one is needed in different scenarios but all of the scenarios depend on variables (some of which come from external sources) so at the point of this function it's impossible to know which ones will be necessary.

So I had a couple of questions about this approach that I hope you guys can answer.

- Is there a negative performance impact when using `Object.defineProperty`, and if yes, is it possible that it could negate the benefit from not parsing the JSON data right away?
- Am I correct in assuming that not parsing the JSON right away will actually improve performance? We're looking at a continuously high number of requests and we need to process these quickly and efficiently.
- Right now the three JSON data sets come from two different tables JOINed in an SQL query. This is to only have to do one query per request instead of up to four. Keeping in mind that there are scenarios where none of the JSON data is needed, but also scenarios where all three data sets are needed (and of course scenarios inbetween), could it be an improvement to only get the required JSON data from its table, at the point when one of the data sets is actually needed? I avoided this because I feel like waiting for four separate SELECT queries to be executed would take longer than waiting for one query with two JOINed tables.
- Are there other ways to approach this that would improve the general performance even more? (I know, this one's a bit of a subjective question, but ideas / suggestions of things I should check out are welcome). I'm not looking to spin off parsing the JSON data into a separate thread though, because as our service runs on a cluster of virtualised single-core servers, creating a child process would only increase overall CPU usage, which at high loads would have even more negative impact on performance.

*Note: when I say performance it mainly means fast and efficient throughput rates. We prefer a somewhat larger memory footprint over heavier CPU usage.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil
>     - Donald Knuth

What do I get from that article? Too much time is spent in optimizing with dubious results instead of focusing on design and clarity.

It's true that JSON.parse blocks the event loop, but every synchronous call does - this is just code execution and is not a bad thing.

The root concern is not that it is blocking, but how long it is blocking. I remember a Strongloop instructor saying 10ms was a good rule of thumb for max execution time for a call in an app at cloud scale. >10ms is time to start optimizing - for apps at huge scale. Each app has to define that threshold.

So, how much execution time will your lazy init save? [This article](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-event-loop-monitoring/) says it takes 1.5s to parse a 15MB json string - about 10,000 B/ms. 3 configs, 50 properties each, 30 bytes/k-v pair = 4500 bytes - about half a millisecond.

When the time came to optimize, I would look at having your lazy init do the MySQL call. A config is needed only 50% of the time, it won't block the event loop, and an external call to a db absolutely dwarfs a JSON.parse().

All of this to say: What you are doing is not necessarily bad or wrong, but if the whole app is littered with these types of dubious optimizations, how does that impact feature addition and maintenance? The biggest problems I see revolve around time to market, not speed. Code complexity increases time to market.

**Q1**: *Is there a negative performance impact when using Object.defineProperty...*

Check out [this site](https://jsperf.com/object-defineproperty-vs-definegetter-vs-normal) for a hint.

**Q2**: *...not parsing the JSON right away will actually improve performance...

IMHO: inconsequentially

**Q3**: *Right now the three JSON data sets come from two different tables...*

The majority db query cost is usually the out of process call and the network data transport (unless you have a really bad schema or config). All data in one call is the right move.

**Q4**: *Are there other ways to approach this that would improve the general performance*

Impossible to tell. The place to start is with an observed behavior, then profiler tools to identify the culprit, then code optimization.

Comment: In my experience with previous applications I developed, JSON parsing is usually a relatively significant performance bottleneck when dealing with a lot of traffic, much more so than a database query, just because queries are handled asynchronously while JSON data is not. Doing the MySQL query in the lazy init is not an option since I do need the user data right away, it's only the config properties that aren't always needed, so a database call has to happen at that point either way. Anyhow, thanks for your response, it has given me some answers and some things to think about.